# The flow generated by integral of motion sends orbits of Hamiltonian into orbit of Hamiltonian?

Tags: dynamical-systems, mathematical-physics, hamilton-equations, celestial-mechanics

I read these two statement in the notes of my teacher that seem to me opposing.
Let $H$ an Hamiltonian and let $\Phi$ an integral of motion of $H$, so that $\Phi$ keeps constant value along the orbit of $H$.

The two statements are the following:

The flow of $\Phi$ sends orbits of $H$ into orbits of ˆ$H$.

The Hamiltonian is invariant under the flow generated by $\Phi$.

My question is: how can the Hamiltonian be costant along the flow of $\Phi$ if the flow of $\Phi$ send the orbits (that is the level curve of $H$) into other orbits? Where am I wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are talking about Hamiltonian in symplectic geometry:

Let $(M,\omega)$ be a symplectic manifold, and $H:M\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ a differentiable function, the Hamiltonian vector field associated to $H$ is defined by $\omega(X_H,.)=dH$.

Let $\phi_t$ the flow of $X_H$, ${d\over{dt}}H(\phi_t)=dH.X(\phi_t(x))=\omega(X_H(\phi_t(x),X_H(\phi_t(x))=0$ since $\omega$ is alternated, we deduce that $H$ is constant along its orbits.

The orbit of $x$ is $\phi_t(x),t\in\mathbb{R}$ which is invariant by $\phi_t$, $\phi_t$ preserves each orbit.

Comment: Onestly, we didn't talk about Hamiltonian in these terms. We used a more elementary concept, i think. However, where is the reference about the first integral in your comment?

Comment: where is the reference about the first integral in your question ?

Comment: The function $\Phi$ that i wrote is the first integral ( I said this in the first lines of question )